# How to put events in a weekly calendar

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Hi i'm making a weekly calendar with php and I wanna put events in the calendar like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EFM2.jpg), but I don't know how to echo the events in the calendar at the correct part of the day.

This is the code I use to echo the calendar :

```
   <?php
                $dt = new DateTime;

                if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['week'])) {
                    $dt->setISODate($_GET['year'], $_GET['week']);
                }else{
                    $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
                }

                $year = $dt->format('o');
                $week = $dt->format('W');
              ?>


            <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Vorige week</a>
            <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Volgende week</a>

            <?php
              $getDatum = $conn->prepare("
                SELECT DISTINCT D.DocentID, CONCAT(D.Voornaam, ' ', D.Achternaam) AS Docentnaam, D.Telefoonnummer, D.Mobiel, D.Email, CO.DatumBegin, CO.DatumEind, O.Onderdeelnaam

                FROM docenten D

                INNER JOIN psentity PE ON D.DocentID = PE.psid
                INNER JOIN docentonderdelen DO ON D.DocentID = DO.DocentID
                INNER JOIN cursusonderdelen CO ON DO.OnderdeelID = CO.OnderdeelID
                RIGHT JOIN onderdelen O ON CO.OnderdeelID = O.OnderdeelID

                WHERE O.OnderdeelID = 6
                AND CO.DatumBegin AND CO.DatumEind BETWEEN '2018-12-10' AND '2019-10-10'
                AND PE.deleted = 0
                LIMIT 3");

              $getDatum->bindParam(':OID', $OID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $getDatum->bindParam(':BeginDatum', $BeginDatum, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
              $getDatum->bindParam(':Einddatum', $Einddatum, PDO::PARAM_STR);

              $getDatum->execute();

              $docenten = array();

              while ($row = $getDatum->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
              {
                  $docenten[] = $row;
              }
```

[Pastebin link to code](https://pastebin.com/znCM8b8r)
Because the code would otherwise be to long. I hope the information I gave is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the time for event in DatumBegin or in a new column (suppose eventTime with format `(H:i:s)`) and create three arrays according to time and then iterate them in different `tr`

```
$morningTime = date("00:00:00");
$afternoonTime = date("12:00:00");
$eveningTime = date("17:00:00");

$morningEvents = [];
$afternoonEvents = [];
$eveningEvents = [];

while ($row = $getDatum->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $dyDate = date($row['eventTime']);
    if($dyDate<$afternoonTime){       // store "Morning Event";
        $morningEvents[] = $row;
    }

    if($dyDate>=$afternoonTime && $dyDate<$eveningTime){    // store "Afternoon Event";
        $afternoonEvents[] = $row;
    }

    if($dyDate>=$eveningTime){  // store "Evening Event";
        $eveningEvents[] = $row;
    }
}
```